# Has the W3C ever published a standard set of meta tags?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Has there ever been a W3C spec on what meta tag names are "valid" in HTML?  I know onotogloies like Dublin Core have developed standard names, but has the W3C ever published anything that says Tag Name X is "valid" or is this all still completely subjective and driven by usage?

I Googled, but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [trying in HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#standard-metadata-names).

The attempt is, however, laughable:

> Extensions to the predefined set of metadata names may be registered in the WHATWG Wiki 
>   MetaExtensions page. [WHATWGWIKI]
>
> Anyone is free to edit the WHATWG Wiki MetaExtensions page at any time to add a type.